# rcurl & innerHTML/innertext (scraping google trends with R)

Tags: r, innerhtml, scrape, rcurl, innertext

I've used rcurl a fair bit for simple text retrieval and simple scraping, but I'm stumped with google trends.  Let's use obama & romney as an example. If you append "&export=1", google trends returns a page displaying the data underlying the graph.

http://www.google.com/trends/explore?q=obama%2C+romney#q=obama%2C%20romney&export=1

On that page, the data lives in the reportContent div, which you can examine by inspecting the element for:

```
<div id="reportContent" class="report-content"> </div>
```

More specifically, it is tucked away in the innerHTML and the innertext properties associated with that div.  I've never seen this before & am wondering how to access that data with rcurl.  I'm also curious, if anyone happens to know, why google does not just present the data in simple html. I'll admit I'm not very knowledgable; I'm reading as much as I can about it, but what I have found out about the innertext property (not much) is not particularly illuminating or helpful in modifying my rcurl script.

Comment: Why don't you download that in CSV format, e.g. (for the above URL): http://www.google.com/trends/trendsReport?hl=en-US&q=obama%2C%20romney&export=1&content=1

Comment: Didn't know how -- thanks!  You've answered my question.

Comment: Just recently a package named GTrends was published which is based on the RCurl library and is supposed to do what you are trying to accomplish. Have a look at [**Just Another R Blog**](http://anotherrblog.blogspot.com/2013/06/introducing-gtrendsr.html)

Comment: daroczig: The problem is that if you try to use this programmatically, you get an error for not signing in to google. And when you do sign in via rcurl, it still throws an error having to do with the login.

Comment: hvollmeier: this package solves my problem -- thanks!

Comment: hvollmeier: gah.  rather, it would have solved my problem except that the package has the same problem I'm having.  Basically rcurl isn't keeping the id & pw that is necessary for downloading from google trends.

Answer (score 0):

You have to login google in order to get multiple trends data, otherwise, it is easy for you to be blocked by google. Google may consider several factors when blocking you, e.g. IP address/ google accounts/device type / machine or human.

I provide a online google trends scraping service on http://www.datadriver.info/scrapdata/?case_task_id=b333f048be31cad3922f1c8c919700f860f5adbe, Using this service, you won't encounter the boring problem "You have reached your quota limit. Please try again later."